# Is it always the case that Driver must be on a Master node (Yes/No) ? Apache-Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, apache-spark, master-slave

Is it always the case that the Driver (as a program that runs the master node) must be on a master node ?

For example, if I setup the ec2 with one master and two workers, does my code that has the main must be executed from the master EC2 instance ?

If answer is NO, what would be the best way to set-up the system where the driver is outside the ec2's master node (lets say, Driver is ran from my computer, while Master and Workers are on EC2)? **Do I always have to use the spark-submit, or can I do it from an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA?**

If answer is YES, what would be the best reference to learn more about it (since I need to provide some sort of a proof)?

Thank you kindly for your answer, references would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it doesn't have to be on the master.

Using `spark-submit` you can use [deploy-mode](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html) to control how your driver is run (either as a `client`, on the machine you run submit on (which could be master or another), or as `cluster`, on the workers).

There is [network communication](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) between the workers and the driver so you want it 'close' to the workers, never across the WAN.

You can [run from inside](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#using-the-shell) a repl (`spark-shell`) which could be accessed from your IDE. If you're using a dynamic language like Clojure, you can also just create a `SparkContext` referencing (through `master`) a local cluster, or the cluster you want to put jobs to, and then code through the repl. In practice it isn't this easy.

Comment: Thank you. How can I set-up the system to avoid the spark-submit, but to simply do the same thing as I would with the spark-submit, from an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ IDEA ?

Comment: @elisah, thank you. I hope this applies to both, cluster and the client mode. Any references (simply to show my boss at work) ?

Comment: Updated answer to explicitly reference the running part of your question.

Comment: @Alister Lee, I have tried the repl option, and compiled the code with a success. However, it did not work with EC2, having the driver outside the master's node... so you are right, it is not as easy as it might appear.